# 3 and 5 likert scale

Tags: likert

I want to know that is it possible to use 3 and 5 point Likert scale questions in the same questionnaire. For example, I have a questionnaire that has 3 parts and I use a 5 point Likert scale for 2 parts and for the 3rd part I am using 3 point Likert scale. Is this permissible?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It might help to (1) add an illustration & (2) explain what analysis you have in mind that you're concerned might be affected by this aspect of the questionnaire design.

Comment: 1 more question, my questionnaire have both qualitative and quantitative part. For quantitative part i chose 5 likert scale but for qualitative part can i use 3 likert scale with interview questions ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that this is not permissible.  How you use the data will depend (as always) on your hypotheses. Whether this is the best solution isn't clear, but it's not "wrong".